# Regex for replacing all newlines that are not after ';'

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to ask if someone could help me out with regex which will match all `\n` except `\n` that is after `;`
Example:

```
test
test1
test2;
test
test1;
test
test1;
```

will be changed to

```
testtest1test2;
testtest1;
testtest1;
```

Comment: Which language/tool are you using for this?

Comment: It will be done in java.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Try and `.replaceAll("(?<!;)\r?\n", "");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
// read complete file in a string
String data = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

// remove all newlines that aren't preceded by semi-colon
String repl = data.replaceAll("(?<!;)(\\r?\\n)+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex can be used to find those lines: `(?<!;)\n` What is means is basically *not a ; followed by a new line*. You can also add a `\r?` before `\n` to accept carriage returns if they can be present in your document, though this will depend on your platform.

Simply replace the matches with `""` (an empty string) to remove the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Look behinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html),this should work-

```
Search for   - (?<!;)\n
Replace with - (Empty string - '')
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/hZ1xV2)